# How to control a Canon 600D (Rebel T3i) and others from a computer?

Tags: remote, canon-600d, tethering

Is there any way to remote control a Canon Rebel T3i 600D from the computer, for example to take shots like every x lapse or something like? I also need the software to do it, I'm looking for a good software that works.

Comment: I use EOS Utility software (DVD comes in your camera box). After connecting your camera through USB and enabling live view, you can select the time interval and number of shots in the software.

Comment: @KamyarSouri yes Kamyar! Thanks! I realized that my software version is pretty old. I've to updated to view the options!

Comment: [How to take photos with PC controlling?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16960/how-to-take-photos-with-pc-controlling) seems to cover several options for Canon DSLRs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At right moment (2021) still the better option is download the EOS Utility from the Canon webpage.

Download the update, but if you don't have the CD or you don't have a DVD Reader (as me), then you can create the following key in the register:

1. Open Notepad.exe
2. Write the following code:

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Canon\EOS Utility]

3. Save the file as "Canon.reg"
4. Double click on the file and you will be prompt if you want to run this into Register. Click Yes.

If everything fine, the installer won't ask for CD.

Still working with Windows 10 and Windows 11, on October 2021

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a video series from Canon's Digital Learning Series that teaches about using the bundled software from Canon to shoot tethered to your PC. There is a section on automated interval sequencing.

http://www.learn.usa.canon.com/galleries/galleries/tutorials/eos_util_isola_gallery.shtml

Answer (score 1):

A free tethering solution http://digicamcontrol.com/ which support Nikon and Canon cameras [Disclaimer: I'm the developer]

Answer (score 0):

I've used DSLR remote pro in the past but the price is a bit steep at $175

Comment: This one? http://www.breezesys.com/DSLRRemotePro/

Answer (score -1):

There's also Helicon Remote software: http://www.heliconsoft.com/heliconsoft-products/helicon-remote/